# Program Fixpoint error with Admit Obligations and nested recursion

Tags: coq

I was trying to define a function using `Program Fixpoint`, which uses another (anonymous) recursive function in its body. I tried using `Admit Obligations`for the moment, to see if something else made sense but I get an error.

This is a simple example that shows the same error (maybe there is a simpler one...).

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.
Require Import Program.

Section Test.

  Inductive FType : Type :=
  | Base : RType -> FType
  | Cons : RType -> FType -> FType
  with RType : Type :=
  | Empty : RType  
  | Nested : nat -> FType -> RType
  | NestedList : nat -> list FType -> RType.


  Variable ftype_size : FType -> nat.


  Program Fixpoint failing (ft : FType) {measure (ftype_size ft)} : FType :=
    match ft with
    | Base _ => ft
    | Cons hd tl =>
      match hd with
      | NestedList l rs =>
        let fix loop (rs : list FType) (i : nat) : list FType :=
            match rs with
            | [] => []
            | r' :: rs' => (failing r') :: (loop rs' (i + 1))
            end
        in
        Base (NestedList l (loop rs 0))                                  
      | _ => ft
      end
    end.
  Admit Obligations.

End Test.
```

So, when running this it says `Recursive call to loop has not enough arguments.`. I was wondering why is this happening? Is it somehow related to this [issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/9226)?

Also, if I define an indexed map and repeat this, I don't get any error.

```
 Section Map.
        Variables (T1 T2 : Type) (f : nat -> T1 -> T2).

Definition indexed_map (s : list T1) :=
  let fix imap s index : list T2 :=
      match s with
      | [] => []
      | hd :: tl =>  (f index hd) :: imap tl (index + 1)
      end
  in
  imap s 0.
  End Map.

  Arguments indexed_map [T1 T2].

  Program Fixpoint failing (ft : FType) {measure (ftype_size ft)} : FType :=
    match ft with
    | Base _ => ft
    | Cons hd tl =>
      match hd with
      | NestedList l rs => Base (NestedList l (indexed_map (fun i r' => (failing r')) rs))                             
      | _ => ft
      end
    end.
  Admit Obligations.
```

I can probably define it in a different way but I was still wondering why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the error message further, notice that `loop` occurs twice in the printed function. The second occurence is the one you wrote, but the first (the problematic one) is an argument to an axiom generated by `Admit Obligations`.

```
Recursive call to loop has not enough arguments.
Recursive definition is:
"fun (rs0 : list FType) (i : nat) =>
 let program_branch_0 := fun _ : [] = rs0 => [] in
 let program_branch_1 :=
   fun (r' : FType) (rs' : list FType) (Heq_rs : r' :: rs' = rs0) =>
   failing r'
     (failing_obligation_1 ft failing hd tl Heq_ft l rs Heq_hd loop
        rs0 i r' rs' Heq_rs) :: loop rs' (i + 1) in
 match rs0 as rs' return (rs' = rs0 -> list FType) with
 | [] => program_branch_0
 | r' :: rs' => program_branch_1 r' rs'
 end eq_refl".
```

To avoid that, you can step through the corresponding obligation manually and put your own axiom that doesn't depend on `loop`.

```
Parameter TODO : forall {A : Prop}, A.

Program Fixpoint failing ... (* Your definition *)

Next Obligation.
  apply TODO.
Qed.

(* Now the rest can still be Admitted. *)
Admit Obligations.
```